# Why does Haskell implement Enum on the Real?

Tags: haskell

The `Enum` typeclass implies that the implementing types can be ordered in some meaningful way.  In Haskell, the `Real` type implements `Enum`.  Coming from a mathematics background, this is very strange.  A hundred years ago, Georg Cantor proved that reals cannot not be indexed, that is, there is no way to say what is the n-th real for all reals.

Now, concrete types such as `Double` do in fact have a finite domain.  So you could argue that they can implement `Enum`.  One would assume the the successor of a `Double` would be the next valid `Double`.  Instead, it is simply the addition of `1`. Hence, we see weirdness like:

```
Prelude> succ (1e20 :: Double) == (1e20 :: Double)
True
```

In my opinion, this behavior breaks the usefulness of `Enum`.  Can anyone explain the reasoning behind this?

Edit:
Corrected `Ord` to `Enum` and clarified that reals are not aleph zero.

Post-Script:
This comment illumined the answer to me:

> Enum Double is nowadays considered a mistake by several Haskellers. It was added to allow e.g. [1.0 .. 20.0] to count with a step of one unit. That required succ to be (+1) instead of the true "next" double. Also, it opens a can of worms since length [1.0 .. 99.5] might be 99 or 100 depending on rounding errors. Worse, this can't be fixed, it's inherently fragile.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Your question claims to be about `Ord` but seems to actually be about `Enum`. `succ` is a method from the `Enum` typeclass, and it's obvious that reals can be totally ordered - I'm not sure which Cantor result you're referring to but I guess it's the fact that the reals are uncountable (with the original version of the famous "diagonal argument"), which does relate to enumeration. You question in short seems to be about why `Double` implements `Enum` - which is an excellent question, I hadn't realised it does until I read your question and looked it up!

Comment: @RobinZigmond Trivially, `Double` can implement `Enum` because it is represented as a finite number of bits, and hence apart from the special values for any `x :: Double` there exists a `y :: Double` where `y>x` but there does not exist a `z` where `y > z > x`. However in practice the `Enum` instance in this and similar cases has `succ = (+1)`, which makes no sense. Maybe its because the "right" answer would depend on the hardware arithmetic.

Comment: `Enum Double` is nowadays considered a mistake by several Haskellers. It was added to allow e.g. `[1.0 .. 20.0]` to count with a step of one unit. That required `succ` to be `(+1)` instead of the true "next" double. Also, it opens a can of worms since `length [1.0 .. 99.5]` might be 99 or 100 depending on rounding errors. Worse, this can't be fixed, it's inherently fragile.

Comment: A historical note: some of the standard typeclasses like `Enum` and `Num` are really just for overloading. They were introduced before Haskell even had an established custom of using typeclasses to model algebraic structures. A lot of us would *like* to update the standard library design (e.g. replacing `Num` with something like `Ring`), but it will be a process, since it affects a lot of code, and requires striking a delicate balance between generality and ergonomics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Robin Zigmond commented, you're confusing the `Ord` and `Enum` classes. `Ord` is what's a superclass of `Real`, but `Enum` is what `succ` belongs to.

`Ord` does not allow you to enumerate, or otherwise generate any elements of a type, it only allows you to compare given elements. And being able to check whether `x < y` for two real numbers would seem perfectly straightforward and uncontroversial.<sup>†</sup>

By contrast, the `Enum` class is an absolute mathematical mess. This is **not** a class for enumerating all values of a type (that would be [`Universe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.1.2/docs/Data-Universe-Class.html#t:Universe)), rather you should just think of it as the class that can be used for list builders of the form `[1, 1.5, .. 9]` or `['q'..]`. These don't really have any clear mathematical interpretation, they're just useful for writing concise practical code.

It has been argued that `Float` and `Double` should not have `Enum` instances. But IMO those instances are ok in as far as the class itself is ok – not good, but not bad enough to warrant the hassle of replacing it with something new (and braking lots of existing code that makes use of list comprehensions).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually, this is worth some consideration. Unlike `x < y`, which is generally a perfectly fine thing to check, `x==y` is actually problematic in some ways, both mathematically for exact reals and practically for floating-point numbers. Speaking constructive-mathematically, all you can do is check in finite time that `x < y` or `x > y`, but you can never be sure that two values are equal. And for floating-point numbers, you should never assume that two values are `==`-equal even if they come out of mathematically equivalent comparisons. Instead, what you should do in testing is to check that `x-ε < y < x+ε` for some small ε. (*How small* is appropriate can be tricky to determine.)</sub>

Comment: Is there a computable algorithm that will always successfully determine whether one real number is less than another? I thought this was impossible, since there are situations where two computable numbers might be *really* close to each other or they could be exactly equal and it wouldn't be possible to tell which, making it semi-decidable. IIRC this is related to why every computable function on the computable reals is continuous, based on [Sections 2 & 4 of this paper for instance (if I understand correctly)](http://math.andrej.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/real-world-realizability.pdf)

Comment: @DavidYoung I think you mean the same what I already expressed: there is no way to tell for sure whether `x==y` or, for example, `x<y`. However, _given that_ `x<y`, it is possible to confirm that. For example, if you define reals as Dedekind cuts, then if `x<y` it follows that there exists a rational number that is both in the right partition of `x` and in the left partition of `y`.

Comment: Thinking of `Enum` as list comprehension makes sense to me:
```
Prelude Data.Int> take 100 $ enumFromThen 0.0 0.5
```
This yields a predictable sequence (list). If `succ Double` is thought of as using the default step of `1.0` then I guess that makes some kind of sense

Comment: @DavidYoung All the comparison operations are semi-decidable for the computable reals. That is, the tests `m == n`, `m < n`, `m > n`, etc., will each terminate if and only if `m≠n`.

Comment: "Given that `x<y`, it is possible to confirm that." Okay, but that doesn't imply there's a decision procedure for `x<y`; a decision procedure must always give an answer. So it is not perfectly fine to check `x<y`. Or, to say it another way: *given that* `x<y`, it is possible to check `x==y`; so why do you distinguish between `==` and `<`?

Comment: @DanielWagner well, given that `x>y`, it would be possible to disprove `x<y`. IOW, for two nonequal numbers, `x<y` _is_ decidable, it's only the equal case that causes trouble. But that's actually not a problem, because two real-world real numbers will _never_ be equal! Specifically, a real measurement has always some amount of noise on it, i.e. random fluctuation from a continuous probability distribution (e.g. Gaussian). And the event of two numbers from such a distribution coming out equal has [probability zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely).

Comment: @leftaroundabout For two nonequal numbers, `x==y` is decidable, it's only the equal case that causes trouble! You don't get to rule out equal numbers when talking about `<` but not when talking about `==`. There's *no difference* in decidability between the two.

Comment: @DanielWagner well, there is a difference in that you can never hope to demonstrate `x==y`, so there's no point even trying. (Almost always you would find that they're nonequal, but that doesn't give you any useful information.) Meanwhile, for random input pairs, there's a 50% chance of demonstrating `x<y`, so that _is_ a useful thing to check. If you will, for all valid inputs `==` is trivially decidable, whereas `<` is only nontrivially decidable.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The definition of decidability only says that an algorithm exists that always answers. If you can only write an algorithm that sometimes doesn't answer, it's not decidable, whether the output it gives is the same whenever it answers or not.

Comment: @DanielWagner well, I didn't bring up the topic of whether the comparison operators fulfill _the definition of decidability_. This is not relevant for practical purposes. The fact that `==` never gives useful results on real numbers is relevant though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm not sure I fully understand your argument. Certainly particular computable reals like `pi` are frequently used and can be exactly represented. If you have, say, the function `f x y = if y < x then 2*y else y+1` and try to compute `map (f pi) [pi-2, pi-1, pi, pi+1, pi+2]` using a computable real representation you will have issues. Numbers do not *exclusively* come from measurements. Certainly `pi`, `e` and square roots of integers, among others, come up a lot in practical applications. I don't see why `(<)` is ok in a way that `(==)` is not here.

Comment: It also seems to me that you would more frequently want to use a computable real representation for things like `pi` rather than for things like real world measurements. The key feature of a computable real representation is that it exactly represents the number to arbitrary precision. We can do this for things like `pi`, but real world measurements have a fundamentally limited precision. So, in that case, we would get the disadvantages of computable real representation (decidability issues) without the advantages (exactly correct to arbitrary precision)

Comment: @DavidYoung I'd say the key feature of a computable real representation is that it **only** computes to whatever precision is required. That it doesn't spend unnecessary work computing subexpressions to a ridiculous precision that has no purpose because you then combine those values with error-laden physical measurements. All that without requiring unreliable fiddling with number-of-iterations parameters. — If you're interested in _exact_ stuff, then you should use a _symbolic_ representation, not computable reals. Symbolically checking π==π is of course possible.

Comment: Also, `map (f pi) [pi-2, pi-1, pi, pi+1, pi+2]` can actually be perfectly ok as long as you don't expect all the results strictly. That's also a great sort of application of computable reals: lazily performing multiple checks, using the the first one that succeeds, discarding the ones that couldn't be decided yet.

Comment: ...A thought Re symbolic: wonder whether there are tools that _combine_ symbolic and computable-reals, as both have kind of the opposite problem: with symbolic you can prove that two terms are equal, but just because you haven't found a way to rewrite two terms to be identical doesn't prove that they're not equal. With computable-real you can prove that two values are unequal, but just because you haven't manages yet doesn't prove that they're equal. — Perhaps Mathematica can do that.

Comment: I was actually just thinking about something similar (although I was thinking more about combining `Rational` with computable reals in some way, since `Rational` has decidable comparisons and would make sense for something like a measurement)! It seems like it would be a pretty useful way to represent certain kinds of numeric quantities. I bet Mathematica does do that, as you said. I wonder if there's a Haskell library...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a mathematician, but my understanding is that real numbers *can* be ordered, they just can't be **well**-ordered.

The [`Ord` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Ord) in Haskell basically just says that for any two elements of the type, you can distinguish whether one is less than, greater than, or equal to the other. Mathematical real numbers support this with the usual ≤ and ≥ relationships.

However the usual order on real numbers is not a [*well-order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order), which would require that every non-empty subset of the reals would have a least element. The Haskell class `Ord` says nothing about finding least elements for arbitrary subsets (or anything equivalent), so there's no problem with a type that purports to represent real numbers being in `Ord`.

When you talk about `succ`, you're asking about the [`Enum` type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum). That has nothing to do with `Ord`<sup>1</sup>.

The `Enum` class is often considered a wart in the language. The few laws it documents actually *mandate* that its implementations should not be total<sup>2</sup>. It defines enumerability by ability to be translated to/from `Int`, which is fundamentally finite while also being too large for any user-defined finite type to have a total `toEnum`. It is *not* a good representation of the mathematical concept of an enumerable set. I don't think `Enum` would end up the way it is if the standard library were being invented from scratch now.

What `Enum` *does* do is support Haskell's `[n..m]` syntax. *This* is why it made sense for non-integral number types like `Double` to have `succ x = x + 1` instead of attempting to find the next representable number. The spec wants `[1..3] :: [Double]` to be `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`, not a list of every representable number between 1 and 3.

So `Double` having an `Enum` instance just isn't a very sensible idea from a pure mathematics point of view (with the `Enum` we have), and neither is the whole `Enum` class itself, but they aren't really intended to be either; pure mathematics wasn't what motivated their creation. If you want to think of `Double`s as representing mathematical reals then `Enum` is just a wart you have to remember to avoid (but also, that is far from your only problem with thinking of `Double`s as reals). There isn't really a hugely satisfying answer to your question. Not everything in Haskell is perfect representation of mathematical concepts.

---

<sup>1</sup> Other than perhaps an implied law that if the type is also in `Ord` then `x < succ x` should hold whenever `succ x` is defined? It's not actually stated as a law, and `Enum` is a pretty ad-hoc class, it's arguable either way, but I'd be a bit disappointed in an instance that didn't satisfy that.

<sup>2</sup> From [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum):

> For any type that is an instance of class Bounded as well as Enum, the
> following should hold:
>
> - The calls `succ maxBound` and `pred minBound` should result in a runtime error.
> - `fromEnum` and `toEnum` should give a runtime error if the result value is not representable in the result type. For example, `toEnum 7 :: Bool` is an error.

Comment: The axiom of choice can be used to (non constructively) prove that any set can be well-ordered, including reals. The issue is that, as you correctly state above, the standard ordering on reals is not a well-order.